# Pyinstaller Executable is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've been using pyinstaller to make .exe file for quit a long time. I've made some .exe file and distributed it across all works fine

Today I created an app to read table from multiple .html file and create a consolidated excel file.

The script is working fine as expected however I am not able to convert that code to .exe file. I have pyinstaller and all the dependencies installed and I am able to convert other codes to .exe. Its just this one is not working

Please check the code below

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_ui(self)
def init_ui(self,Consolidate):
    Consolidate.setObjectName("Consolidate")
    Consolidate.resize(410, 300)
    self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Consolidate)
    self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 381, 23))
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
    self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Consolidate)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 30, 51, 21))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("browse")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Consolidate)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 291, 21))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Consolidate)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 250, 131, 41))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("go")
    self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Consolidate)
    self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 351, 141))
    self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")

    self.retranslateUi(Consolidate)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Consolidate)

def retranslateUi(self, Consolidate):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Consolidate.setWindowTitle(_translate("Consolidate", "Consolidate Excel"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Consolidate", "Browse"))
    self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Consolidate", "Please Browse The Target Folder"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Consolidate", "Go"))


    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.fname)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.go)

    folder = str()
def fname(self):
    global folder
    file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Folder"))
    folder = (file)
    print (folder)
    self.lineEdit.setText(folder)

def go(self):
    import pandas as pd
    dflist = list()

    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        if os.path.isdir(path) or file == "QtoolAssigned.xlsx":
            continue
        else:
            print(file)
            self.textBrowser_2.append(file[7:-28])

            df = pd.read_html(path)
            df = df[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
            df['Team Name'] = str(file[7:-28])

            dflist.append(df)
        concatdf = pd.concat(dflist,axis=0)

    concatdf.to_excel(folder+'\\'+'QtoolAssigned.xlsx', index=None)
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value",100)

if __name__=='__main__':
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Window()
ex.show()
app.exec_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What did you expect to see, and what diagnostic message did you see instead?

Comment: I was expecting a UI where I can browse some files and get a consolidated file in output but i am getting error message instead..  "failed to execute. main"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app didn't run because your app has a bug in it. You didn't give us the stack trace that would let us determine where the bug is. You didn't tell us how you invoked pyinstaller to build the app.

Please follow this advice on obtaining a stack trace: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2015#issuecomment-222408252

Running your application as an .exe will happen in a different environment than as a script, so imports and dynamic linking will happen differently. You may find it helpful to start with a brand new test script that you know works, based on past successes, and then one-by-one pull in new features from your failing script, until you encounter the item that breaks things. The vague problem description we have at present makes it hard to be more specific, as we can't see what you see. A little time spent debugging should quickly reveal the troublesome part of your app.